# not able to attach content type to page layout using csom

Tags: 2013, csom, page-layout

I am trying to attach a content type to a page layout

```
private void attachContentType(string siteURL, string path, string filename, ClientContext ctx, string folderName)
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + folderName + filename);
            ctx.Load(home);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            home.ListItemAllFields["ContentTypeId"] = web.ContentTypes.GetByName("Page Layout").Id;
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

This does not throw any error, but when I edit properties of the pagelayout, its still showing `Design File` only

Comment: I think home.ListItemAllFields.Update(); was  missed.

Comment: Added my solution as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you  missed `home.ListItemAllFields.Update();`

```
home.ListItemAllFields["ContentTypeId"] = web.ContentTypes.GetByName("Page Layout").Id;
home.ListItemAllFields.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Note, it will only work on the `RootWeb`, so you might need to the change the web object accordingly, somewhat like `Web web = ctx.Site.RootWeb`:

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery");
ContentTypeCollection contentTypeColl = list.ContentTypes;
ctx.Load(contentTypeColl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ContentType contentType=null;
foreach (ContentType ct in contentTypeColl)
{
    if (ct.Name == "Page Layout")
    {
        contentType = ct;
        break;
    }   
}

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File home = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + folderName + filename);
ctx.Load(home);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
home.ListItemAllFields["ContentTypeId"] = contentType.Id.ToString();
home.ListItemAllFields["Content Type"] = contentType.Name;
home.ListItemAllFields.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```